# Why won't the audio switch back to my Internal Speakers after having used Apple TV?

Tags: audio, appletv, airplay, speakers

When I extend my MacBook display to my TV using my Apple TV, both the video and audio work well, being output through my TV.

However, when I disconnect my Apple TV, the video disconnects, but audio from my computer is still output through my TV.

I tried going to System Preferences > Sound and toggling the output back to my Internal Speakers, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any idea why?

Comment: what does not seem to work ?

Comment: did you select where to play the music? internal speakers or the AirPlay device.

Answer (score 1):

I have had [something similar on the Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110126/17128) when directing sound vai the say command to my Apple Tv and then back to the Built in output.

I would have to run the command to switch back twice to get it back

You could open Terminal.app  and type and run

```
say -a 38 "I am Back"
```

a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem happen to me in the past. I have found that restarting my Mac tends to fix the problem.

Try restarting your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Quit the coreaudio task in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset both your Mac and the TV, that works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s how to quickly fix the missing audio output on a Mac. And yes, this applies to all Macs with all forms of speakers; internal, external, headphones, earbuds, etc:

Head to the  Apple menu and choose “System Preferences”, then select the “Sound” panel
Choose the “Output” tab
Select “Internal Speakers” as the output device*
Adjust the sound as usual, it will now work as intended

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the OP already said didn't work...